# How to install additional LaTeX packages in Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu

I just installed `texlive-latex-base` package from official Ubuntu repo, now I have to add some modules (`ucs` and `utf8x`) for compiling .pdf files with Cyrillic encoding, so, how to install it? I found `tlmgr` - the TeX Live manager, but I have no such command, it seems that I could install tlmgr using [this](http://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html): "You may end up in a situation where tlmgr itself does not run due to Perl errors, failed updates, or some other reason. If this happens, the simplest way forward is to download and run [update-tlmgr-latest.sh](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh)" Am I right?

Update:

```
argon@vprime:~/Documents/diplom$ sudo bash update-tlmgr-latest.sh 
[sudo] password for argon: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater..........................................................................................................................................................................
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: Please call update-tlmgr-latest.sh --noexec --keep
./runme.sh: and then call the runme.sh script in the unpacked directory
./runme.sh: with the directory root as the first argument, something like:
./runme.sh: sh runme.sh /path/to/your/texlive/installation/2010
argon@vprime:~/Documents/diplom$ dpkg -L tex
tex-common          texlive-binaries    texlive-doc-base
texlive-base        texlive-common      texlive-latex-base
```

So, path to which package should i use?

Comment: @You what do you mean 'you probably want all...', Im asking about which package's directory I should use like argument for runme.sh, also - there are many directories for each package...

Comment: `tlmgr` has nothing to do with the Ubuntu TeX Live (which is from 2009). `tlmgr` is only available in the version of TL you can get from TUG, see tug.org/texlive. If you want the latest, go with TUG TL 12, not the Ubuntu TL

Comment: Could someone find a more specific title for this question? I feel like it should at least mention Ubuntu.

Comment: @doncherry -- Judging from the comment to the answer below, the (real) question seems to have been 'how to install *tex packages using the native Debian/Ubuntu repositories', which I'm guessing has been answered before.  (That answer in turn should point to how to install the current version of TL, the relative merits of using Debian/Ubuntu's version over current TL, etc.)

Comment: @jon I'm not really familiar with the entire Linux topic, but that sounds plausible. Feel free to act accordingly as you feel appropriate, with editing, flagging as duplicate and whatnot.

Comment: @doncherry -- I edited the title.  I don't know what to do about the flagging thing.  It seems like there are a lot of 'how do I install X in Ubuntu' questions here.  Can we have one 'big' generic question and close all the others as duplicates?  (Really, there two choices will cover 99% of all users: install native Debian packages or install TL directly from CTAN.)

Comment: @jon Thanks! One big canonical question sounds like a great idea, in general -- probably in this case as well, but I'm not an expert on that topic. If you're unsure, you could post a question on [meta] first. Generally, the community responds really well to canonical questions. (You should probably state explicitly that your question is intended to be one.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The most straightforward you can do is to open Synaptic package manager, or Ubuntu software center, or whatever other distro manager you have and look for a system package which enhances your TeX distribution with packages you need.
2. The second option you have is to get the packages you need from CTAN, install (unpack) them into your `LOCALTEXMF` tree and rerun `texhash` so that your TeX will find them. This however might sound easier than it is for more complex packages, fonts, bibliography styles, etc.
3. The last option, is to download and install the latest [TeXLive](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) distribution, where you would have `tlmgr` and friends. If you have a good network connection and enough space on your disk, just go with the full installation.

Personally, I very much recommend to go with the last option, that is the full TeXLive install from scratch. The point is that Ubuntu still ships TeXLive 2009 packages, while recently TeXLive 2012 came out. Going with the most recent distro will ensure that you will have all the new things done in XeTeX, or LuaTeX which might be of your interest, since as you speak you are after non-latin fonts/encodings and such.

Before doing the full TeXLive install, do not forget to purge the Ubuntu TeXLive 2009 installation, otherwise the two will clash.

Comment: thanks:) Im already solve it by adding packages(ubuntu 12.04): `texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-lang-cyrillic 
scalable-cyrfonts-tex `