# How to get mdframed package working correctly?

Tags: texlive, mdframed, ubuntu, zref

On a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits system, I wanted to add the mdframed package to my `texlive` distribution.

After searching in Ubuntu standard repositories without success, I went to the CTAN website to download and manually compile and install the package. I did it and put this in the `texmf` directory tree in my home and after running `texhash` on this directory I got a new error when compiling about missing `xparse` package.

I repeated the same, and found this package in the texlive-latex3 standard Ubuntu package. So I installed it through `apt-get` and now I am getting the following other error that I can't solve:

```
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty:94: Missing \begin{document}.
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: I guess that is a problem with the too old TeX Live packages in Ubuntu 12.04. There are ppa for TeX Live 2012 packages, where mdframed is also included. Using this is probably the best option. Or you get TeX Live upstream from tug.org/texlive

Comment: Thanks for the comment. ubuntu 12.04 provides texlive TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) that seems to be quite old. Unfortunately changing this seems to appear a big change to my eyes. Isn't it ?

Comment: The alternative is maintaining a separate texmf tree (home or local) with manually updated packages.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek As I see your name in the package hierarchy I guess you are the author of the package ;-) Do you confirm that this is an issue with Ubuntu too old texlive version ? I didn't get the point of your alternative solution (I am really new to latex), can you explain a little bit more ? Many thanks

Comment: After TL 2009, the `LaTeX3` packages changed dramatically: from `expl3` (I think) to `l3*`.  A base install of Debian's version of TL (i.e., 2009), will have the wrong version of `xparse`, etc.  You need to purge the `expl3` stuff and install the `.tds.zip` versions of `l3experimental`, `l3kernel`, and `l3packages` (the last has the current version of `xparse`). I said 'purge' because if you merely install the `l3*` stuff, most packages will continue to try to use the `expl3` ones, which won't work.

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65767/5763). Forget about TL from Ubuntu and use virgin TL2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of lines in `zref-abspage.sty` is 66 in recent versions. In the history I could not find a hint that could explain more than 28 additional lines. What contains line 94 with two lines before and after?

You can recreate the file, if the sources are installed. Make a scratch directory, copy the file zref.dtx there and unpack it, e.g.:

```
mkdir /tmp/zref-scratch
cd /tmp/zref-scratch
cp /usr/share/texmf-texlive/source/latex/oberdiek/zref.dtx .
tex zref.dtx
```

This should generate lots of style files with `zref-abspage.sty` among them. Note that you need plain TeX, not LaTeX. Otherwise the documentation would be generated.
The two files can be compared:

```
diff -u /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty zref-abspage.sty
```

Are there differences?

- If yes, what are the differences? The wrong file can then be renamed (for safety and further analysis) and replaced:

  ```
  sudo mv -i /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage-saved.sty
  sudo cp /tmp/zref-scratch/zref-abspage.sty /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
  ```
- If no, Which version you are using? Look into the file `zref-abspage.sty`.

---

My recommendation would be to install the original TeX Live, "howto"s can be found in the net, e.g.:

- [Enrico Gregorio: Installing TeX Live 2010 on Ubuntu](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf)

---

The alternative is installing manually updated packages in a local TDS tree (for all users) or in the home texmf tree (`~/texmf`) for the current user only. The Ubuntu documentation contains a section about [LaTeX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX).

To identify the local tree you can try:

```
kpsewhich --expand-var '$TEXMFLOCAL'
```

The home tree usually is `~/texmf`.

If the package provides a `.tds.zip` file, then the installation is easy. As example
I am using my bundle to install in the home texmf tree:

```
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/oberdiek.tds.zip
unzip oberdiek.tds.zip -d ~/texmf
```

In case of the local texmf tree, `texhash` needs to be called:

```
sudo texhash
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer I didn't read yet ;-) To answer to your first question: wc -l /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty returns 53. It's really strange !!! ???

Comment: To answer to the second question, I don't have the sources :-(

Comment: 53 lines for the old version look more reasonable, therefore I think, `zref` is correctly installed and assume that the message is wrong. Check the `.log` file directly. And if you need `expl3` and `xparse` the Ubuntu version is way too old.

Comment: the log file contains a lot of thing. Difficult to get into it. Anyway I think I need to update to Tex Live 2010 or even more recent. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: The first error message would be interesting. Current is TeX Live 2012.

Comment: Package zref Info: New property list: main on input line 419.
Package zref Info: New property: default on input line 420.
Package zref Info: New property: page on input line 421.
)
\c@abspage=\count137
Package zref Info: New property: abspage on input line 49.
)
\mdf@templength=\skip54
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.94 \DeclareListParser*{\mdf@dolist}{,
                     }
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

Comment: The closing parentheses in `... 49.)` shows that the file `zref-abspage.sty` is already read. And because of `\mdf@templength=\skip54` right before the error message the problem is in `mdframed.sty`. Therefore you should at least update that package.