# How to change color in an environment?

Tags: color, environments

I have an environment defined as follows:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.55,0}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,1}

\newenvironment{comment}{
  \medskip
  \begin{framed}
    \color{red}
    {\textbf{I say: }}
}{
\end{framed}
  \medskip
}
```

After leaving the environment the color is not restored and so it is still red. Should I restore it explicitly somewhere?

Comment: can you make a complete document showing all packages used. It is very hard to debug a fragment. Looks like a bug in something not being "color safe" as defined by the color package documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you may have a look to the [`mdframed`](http://marcodaniel.github.com/mdframed/) package to define your own colored environment.

Comment: I can't used mdframed because of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71345/how-to-get-mdframed-package-working-correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `framed` messes up with colors; just declare the color before entering the environment:

```
\newenvironment{comment}
  {\par\medskip
   \color{red}%
   \begin{framed}
   \textbf{I say: }\ignorespaces}
 {\end{framed}
  \medskip}
```

I've reformatted the code and inserted the important `\ignorespaces`; remember that spaces (or end-of-lines) that don't follow a control sequence are significant. For the same reason, any environment whose "begin" part starts a paragraph should issue `\ignorespaces`: this gobbles the space after `\begin{comment}` (it's an end-of-line, but it's the same to TeX).

This definition will produce a red frame. If you want a black frame, then

```
\newenvironment{comment}
  {\par\medskip
   \begin{framed}
   \begingroup\color{red}%
   \textbf{I say: }\ignorespaces}
 {\endgroup\end{framed}
  \medskip}
```

will do.

Comment: why did you add \par ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva It's true that `framed` starts a new paragraph, but the `\medskip` command is usually better placed between paragraphs. The `\par` ensures correct behavior even if you don't leave an empty line before `\begin{comment}`.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest fix seems to be insert the colored text inside a group.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}   

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.55,0}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,1}

\newenvironment{comment}{
  \medskip
  \begin{framed}
    \bgroup\color{red}
    {\textbf{I say: }}
}{
\egroup\end{framed}
  \medskip
}

\begin{document}
Foo.
\begin{comment}
Here is the content of the \verb!comment! environment.
\end{comment}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

An easy option is to make color environments, even nested and mixed with `\textcolor`:

[image: MWE ouput]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,1}

\newenvironment{comment}{
  \medskip
\begin{color}{red}
\begin{framed}
\begin{color}{blue}
    \textcolor{purple}{\textbf{I say: }} 
}{
\end{color}
\end{framed}
\end{color}
  \medskip
}

\begin{document}
Normal text before
\begin{comment}
 ... Hello
\end{comment}
Normal text after
\end{document}
```