# Using mdframed: can't install xparse.sty

Tags: mdframed, xparse

I have a latex document which uses the mdframed package (OBS: I can successfully compile it on another system).

I installed the mdframed package (through `tlmgr install mdframed`) but when I try to compile, it is still missing the xparse.sty file. I've searched it and it seems xparse.sty belongs to this `xpackage` package.

But `tlmgr install xpackage` fails with "xpackages not present in package repository"

Comment: Check this, sounds like the same problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71345/how-to-get-mdframed-package-working-correctly

Comment: @Xpackage Your information is out-of-date. You want `sudo install l3kernel` and `sudo install l3packages`.

Comment: Followed Joseph Wright's instructions and it worked: tlmgr install l3kernel tlmgr install l3packages Thanks.
(don't really have an stackexchange account, and am in a different PC, so I can't accept it)

Comment: On that basis, 'too localized'