# How to install cjk font to ubuntu LaTeX

Tags: ubuntu, cjk

I found online a LaTeX template for a Chinese CV. There is a line of code:

```
\usepackage[adobefonts]{cjk}
```

The error is that `cjk.sty` not found.

So it seems that I need to install such package. However I am a beginner of Ubuntu and have no idea on how to install such font. Does anyone know how to install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install additional LaTeX packages in Debian/Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65762/how-to-install-additional-latex-packages-in-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Papiro: The problem kww meets is not about CJK fonts, but package file not found.

Answer (score 7):

`sudo apt-get install latex-cjk-all`  can solve your problem

Comment: That uses 0.7GB of disk space. Surely there is a more specific answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the code you use is wrong. Linux is a case-sensitive OS. You should use `CJK` package in uppercase:

```
\usepackage{CJK}
```

And furthermore, `CJK` package has no `adobefonts` option. `CJK` package is a low-level package for CJK support. The `adobefonts` option belongs to `ctex` package. Say, the code you want is probably:

```
\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex}
```

The previous question is helpful to you: [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to install texlive and then run the last option of your solution in the previous question. It worked. Now I am trying to add more Chinese fonts. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @kww: You should read the document of `xeCJK`. There're `\setCJKfamilyfont`, `\CJKfamily`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I input `xelatex file_name` in the terminal, then it works.